# Получить значение аттрибута из HTML строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка

```
<div class="value1 666"></div>
```

Как с помощью PHP и Regex получить массив из двух значений `value1` и `666` ?

Мое текущее решение:

```
    $regex = "/(?:.*class[ ]*=[ ]*[\"\'])(.*)(?:[\"\'].*)/";
    $html = "<div class='value1 666'></div>";
    preg_match_all($regex, $html, $results);
    var_dump($results);
```

Имеет след недостатки :

- в массиве `$results` первое значение всегда входная строка
- коректно работает только если у атрибута задано одно значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("/class\s*=\s*[\"']([^\"'\s]*)\s*([^\"'\s]*)[\"']/", $input, $output);
```

Искомые данные будут содержаться в `$output[1]` и `$output[2]`:

```
preg_match_all("/class\s*=\s*[\"']([^\"'\s]*)\s*([^\"'\s]*)[\"']/", 
"<div class='value1 666'></div><div class='value2 333'></div>", $output);

var_dump($output[1]):
    array(
        0   =>  value1
        1   =>  value2
    )
var_dump($output[2]):
    array(
        0   =>  666
        1   =>  333
    )
```

[Онлайн тест выражения](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iFX)

Answer (score 1):

Для парсинга html воспользуйтесь готовой библиотекой, к примеру phpQuery
https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocument('<div class="value1 666"></div>');
$divs = $document->find('div');

$result = array();
foreach ($divs as $_div) {
    $class = pq($_div)->attr('class');
    $result[] = explode(' ', $class);
}

var_dump($result);
```

regexp -  формальный язык поиска и осуществления манипуляций с подстроками в тексте. А не парсер чего либо...